# Profiling for runtime in C

Tags: c, profiling

i am trying to find out a way in which i can write out run-time of selected number of functions when my tool runs. let say out of large list of functions which my tool have i need to write out the what is the time taken by individual calls y(), z() , a1() ....

```
X(){

 y();
 ..
 ..
 z();
 ..
 ..
 a1();
 ..
 ..
 b1();
 ..
 ..
}
```

I don't want to use gprof because it need to be separately run , and there is no way customer can run gprof at there end.  In many cases i don't have access to the test which is producing long runtime. A way to log run time of high level function will be helpful. i dont't want to wrap around each and every function call around time() system call and then print it. Can macro help in this.? any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you don't want to wrap each call, but let me just show you how I handle timer calls so they can be removed at compile time, and maybe that can be wrapped up in another macro later:

```
#ifndef NOTIME
#  include <ctime>
#  define CLOCK_TICK(acc, ctr)  ctr = std::clock()
#  define CLOCK_TOCK(acc, ctr)  acc += (std::clock() - ctr)
#  define CLOCK_RESET(acc) acc = 0
#  define CLOCK_REPORT(acc) 1000. * double(acc) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)

static clock_t t1a, t1c, t2a, t2c; // as many pairs as you need

#else
#  define CLOCK_TICK(acc, ctr)
#  define CLOCK_TOCK(acc, ctr)
#  define CLOCK_RESET(acc)
#  define CLOCK_REPORT(acc) 0
#endif
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
CLOCK_RESET(t1a);
for (int i = 0; i != 250000; ++i)
{
  CLOCK_TICK(t1a, t1c);
  some_expensive_function();
  CLOCK_TOCK(t1a, t1c);
}
std::cout << "Time spent in some_expensive_function(): " << CLOCK_REPORT(t1a) << "ms.\n";
```

With variadic macros you might even be able to wrap up the function call:

```
#define timed_call(ACC, CTR, func, ...) do { CLOCK_TICK(ACC, CTR); \
                                             func(__VA_ARGS__);    \
                                             CLOCK_TOCK(ACC,CTR);  \
                                           } while (false)
```

Comment: so now for each function call i need to do two call one normal other which is wrapped inside timed_call()?

Comment: The problem is in this case i need to change whole bunch of function calls and wrap it around timed_call().

Comment: @David: Yeah, this approach has many limitations... you'd call a function `foo(x,y,z);` as `timed_call(t1a, t1c, foo, x, y, z);`. I think the most important improvement would be to allow for a return value. I'm not sure if you could add this feature entirely without touching any code...

Answer (score 1):

Your customer does not need to run gprof. If you compile your executable with profiling he just needs to run the app normally, then collect the `gmon.out` data file and deliver it to you. You will then run gprof to generate profiling data.

If you want to have more control over what parts of your code are profiled then you could try the open source [Shiny](http://code.google.com/p/shinyprofiler/) profiler. To use this you have link with a small C++ library and insert a macro at the beginning of each function you want to profile. There are also options to profile blocks of code. The profiler output is generated via a function call from your application, so you can decide how and when the output is generated.

Comment: Doesn't the profiling code make the program much bigger and slower?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I would imagine this would be used only until the performance problems are addressed.

Comment: @Miguel thanks for proving link to Shiny profiler. Giving instrumented build (-pg) to customer is not possible. instrumented build runs are extremely slow. I don't find much documentation for Shiny Profiler. Is this widely used?

Answer (score 1):

Why not wrap each call, with a macro like this:

```
#define WRAP(fcall) do {\
  .. before stuff .. \
  fcall; \
  .. after call .. \
  } while(0)
```

then in place of each

```
foo(x, y, z);
```

you write

```
WRAP(foo(x, y, z));
```

Then if you want to disable it, just comment out the before/after stuff.

It may not be pretty, but it works.

Comment: this is a very nice way... the only problem is now i need to wrap around all of my functions (which is big number around WRAP() call). is there any way i can do  wrap all function in a file around WRAP()?

Comment: @David: Editor macro? It might take all day, but once it's done it's done.

Comment: i think its not the problem of doing one time .. the bigger problem is it make the code look ugly especially when it is scattered around the code in many functions.

Comment: @David: Ugly is in the eye of the beholder :-)